# Remove extra space between divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a array of images (images are of different height) coming from the database (php & mysql) and in the ouput, some extra space is coming under each line. I need to remove that extra space. You can check this http://screencast.com/t/khkvThvsgKR7

Comment: without html and css we can only guess

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: From what it looks like you're going for, this jQuery Masonry plugin might be useful: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide next time your code. Don't post some link to image or site. Content of that link may change. Because of that your question is downvoted.

Here you can see CSS3 solution: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

And here is jQuery Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html

P.S. Before everything, use Google. Try to find something, to learn, to understand. I can explain to you these examples, but I will leave that to you.